# Connecting SQL Server to Cloudera CDH

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, cloudera

I'm very new to Hadoop. I want to connect SQL Server 2008 to Hadoop.
Can anyone give me the steps to do this? Anyone answering this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache Sqoop for this purpose.
you can use Sqoop for efficiently transferring bulk data between Apache Hadoop and structured data stores such as relational databases.

Use the following [link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cloudera.com%2Fcontent%2Fcloudera-content%2Fcloudera-docs%2FCDH4%2F4.2.0%2FCDH4-Installation-Guide%2Fcdh4ig_topic_13.html&ei=VqS7U7iUBsqiugTFloCoCg&usg=AFQjCNFDjjv18PUY0Kfs-Y2cBXsbYzUUfA) to install Sqoop